# Minecraft Coders Pack Errors when Running in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

Okay I am trying to make minecraft mods using eclipse. I used [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1J9t5yFkfQ) video to set it up. I added both ModLoader and GuiApi to the Jar files before decompiling. It works until I try to test it in Eclipse then I get these errors:

```
    Failed to load mod from "mod_HeroesGuild.class"
Exception in thread "Minecraft main thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:140)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:438)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.src.CanvasMojangLogo.<init>(CanvasMojangLogo.java:22)
    at net.minecraft.src.PanelCrashReport.<init>(PanelCrashReport.java:103)
    at net.minecraft.src.MinecraftImpl.displayUnexpectedThrowable(MinecraftImpl.java:26)
    at net.minecraft.src.ModLoader.ThrowException(ModLoader.java:1612)
    at net.minecraft.src.ModLoader.init(ModLoader.java:714)
    at net.minecraft.src.ModLoader.AddAllRenderers(ModLoader.java:121)
    at net.minecraft.src.RenderManager.<init>(RenderManager.java:72)
    at net.minecraft.src.RenderManager.<clinit>(RenderManager.java:168)
    ... 3 more
```

I am new to programming and I don't have any idea what to do...
The run system starts minecraft the mojang logo appears but then I get a white screen! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a forum where someone had the same error:

http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/236195-crashing-after-mojang-logo-problem-solved/

The answer they give is to **reinstall**, via instructions at:

http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Minecraft_Help_FAQ#Reinstalling_Minecraft

...and the poster replies:

> didn't think to delete the whole .minecraft.
>   Problem cured.

Remember to back it up first.

**Underlying cause**

I'm thinking your SDK is somehow loading from/conflicting with your existing Minecraft install.

This is because `.minecraft` is the folder under the Application Data folder that contains minecraft user/runtime data.  Basically, your save game data, and the program's cached data.